# Correct locking for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Apologies for the basic nature of this question by SQL, but it comes from a SQL noob.

I've created the following stored procedure after some online research. The aim of the the procedure is to maintain count (`VisitCount`), so the appropriate locking is necessary to maintain integrity. As far as I understand `MERGE` gives the correct level of lock for this scenario but I'd appreciate it if someone could advise whether this is correct or not.

Thanks.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Popularity_Update
    @TermID int
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @Now date = SYSDATETIME()

   BEGIN TRY
        MERGE Popularity AS t
        USING (SELECT @TermID AS TermID, @Now AS VisitDate) AS s ON t.TermID = s.TermID 
                                                                 AND t.VisitDate = s.VisitDate

        WHEN MATCHED THEN
           UPDATE 
              SET VisitCount += 1

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
           INSERT (TermID, VisitDate, VisitCount)
           VALUES (s.TermID, s.VisitDate, 1);

     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
     END CATCH
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking but your query is highly unlikely to do what you want. You will not get a match unless the value in VisitDate matches exactly the current time. SYSDATETIME is accurate to the second with 7 decimal places.

Comment: Oh I didn't see you had it declared as a date.

Comment: Shoudnt you have a trigger rather than calling a procedure

Comment: @SeanLange - was just about to reply - it does work, albeit i'm testing in my own environment, so I'm unsure about the locking.

Comment: @Mihai - a trigger on what? Do other database changes are being made, so how would a trigger be triggered?

Comment: You also should add something to your catch block. When you have a try catch with an empty catch it is not really error handling, it is error suppression. I really don't see anything wrong with your code at all.

Comment: @SeanLange - Thanks for that Sean - what would you recommend in the TRY/CATCH?

Comment: Unless you need to do some logging that an error occurred it is often a good idea to let the error happen and it will bubble back to the application. This allows the ability to know something went wrong and inform the user. This lets you handle the errors at the application level.

Comment: @SeanLange - I guess the easy part is removing the TRY/CATCH, but how would I report an error in place of it?

Comment: You would want the error to go to your application right? That means you don't handle it at all in sql. Let it crash. The connection will report back to your application that an error occurred. In your application you have a try/catch so you can handle them gracefully.

Comment: @SeanLange - ak, ok that sounds ok

Answer (score 0):

How about this....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Popularity_Update
    @TermID int
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Now date = SYSDATETIME()

    BEGIN TRY

        UPDATE Popularity
        SET VisitCount = COALESCE(VisitCount, 0) + 1
        WHERE TermID = @TermID
        AND  VisitDate = @Now

        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Popularity (TermID, VisitDate, VisitCount)
        VALUES (@TermID,  @Now, 1)
        END  

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH 
END
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing as the OP. Well this is the way we had to do it before MERGE.

Comment: It certainly is not, MERGE statement is a bad news, and should stay away from it. I dont seed the point of using a Merge statement anyway with only two variables.

Comment: @M.Ali - As I said previously, I'm no SQL expert, so will have to look to other SQL guru's for guidance

Comment: I would not use a MERGE here either. MERGE has some issues but something this simple it will work fine.

Comment: "Some Issues" there are 9 Active bugs logged against MERGE check Microsoft Connect :) , I would stay away from an approach which works in some circumstances and doesnt in others , why bother with that anyway :)

Comment: @M.Ali - I'll go back to my original question - if your code is better does the sproc in its current format provide adequate locking to ensure integrity if multiple updates are requested simultaneously?

Comment: The first Update statement will always get an Exclusive Lock on the resources, if a row exists no other connection will be able to access it untill the update statement releases the exclusive locks, <here at this point> there are no locks on the table before the insert statement and after the update statement has completed. Mind by the logic of this procedure sounds like it will be executed quite often, do you really want the rows locked down so often ?

Comment: @M.Ali - I'd rather not lock at all but if this is the only way of achieving it what other choice do I have? I'm just trying to protect against the possibility of multiple attempted inserts for the same term at the same time.